# Struggling with plugin dev basics: add_action

Tags: hooks, actions

I've done a lot of reading, but I'm just really struggling to get my head around it.

I am trying to write a plugin that catches User Registrations/Password changes/deletion and subsequently update a phpbb installation.

I am using a plugin called User Registration. From a google search, I got their action hook when a user validates their account by email ('user_registration_check_token_complete'). I added this code to my plugin, and it worked, mainly (I'll cover the wms_get_user_by use later in this post). This catches the email verification as you can see it in the log:

```
// ACTION New User Varifies Email:
add_action( 'user_registration_check_token_complete', 'wpps_track_user_email_confirmation', 10, 2 );
function wpps_track_user_email_confirmation( $user_id, $user_reg_successful ) {
    write_log("ur_track_user_email_confirmation triggered");

    // $user_reg_successful is either true or false. If it is false then the user's email is not verified yet.
    if( $user_reg_successful === true ) {
        //Use your code here to track event
        write_log("User reg successfull. User ID: " . $user_id);
        $user = wms_get_user_by( 'ID', $userID );
        write_log('Username: ' . $user->user_login);
        global $regpassword;
    }
}
```

I also want to catch admin approvals, so I opened up the User Registration plugin in Visual Studio code and did a search in 'includes' on "do_action" This returned a number of possible functions that deal with that. From this, I added the following to my plugin:

```
// ACTION New User Approved
add_action( 'ur_user_approved', 'wpps_ur_user_approved', 10, 1);
function wpps_ur_user_approved( $userID) {
    write_log("New User approved. User ID: " . $userid);    
}

// ACTION: User Status updated:
add_action( 'ur_user_status_updated', 'wpps_ur_user_status_updated', 10, 3);
function wpps_ur_user_status_updated($status,$userID,$alertUser) {
    write_log("User status updated. User ID: " . $userid);  
}

// ACTION Failed Login
add_action( 'user_registration_login_failed' , 'wpps_user_registration_login_failed', 10);
function wpps_user_registration_login_failed() {
    write_log("Login fail");
}

// ACTION User Resets Password
add_action( 'user_registration_reset_password', 'wpps_user_registration_reset_password', 10, 1);
function wpps_user_registration_reset_password($user_id) {
    write_log("User reset password. User ID: " . $user_id); 
}
```

None of these are caught. I really don't think it's that they're not getting fired. It must be my coding.

I also tried to access a wordpress hook, just to check that it's not related to the registration plugin. I borrowed from another plugin I wrote which retrieves user details via ID ([link here](https://magoarcade.org/wp/mantisbt-wordpress-plugin/)). The function:

```
function wms_get_user_by( $field, $value ) {
    $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value ); 
    if ( ! $userdata ) {
        return false;
    } 
    $user = new WP_User;
    $user->init( $userdata ); 
    return $user;
}
```

And implementation is in the first function at the top of the post. This didn't work, sadly, as no username is visible in the log (although, weirdly, it works in my other plugin).

I'm either missing some php syntax (php not my first language - usually .net) or majorly misunderstanding wordpress mechanics. Please help! Full code below to anbale checking of syntax etc:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: WP-PhpBbSync
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: Syncs user creation and password creation/change between Wordpress and PhpBB
 * Version: 0.8
 * Author: stigzler
 * Author URI: http://www.magoarcade.org
 */

// Settings ==========================================================

// Log File ==========================================================
function write_log ($txt) {
    $myfile = fopen("WP-PhpBbSync-log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile,  "\n". date('h:i:s ', time()) . $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}

// ACTION Head (to make sure it's registering)
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wps_wp_head', 100 );
function wps_wp_head() {
    write_log("wp-head");
}

// ACTION New User Varifies Email:
add_action( 'user_registration_check_token_complete', 'wpps_track_user_email_confirmation', 10, 2 );
function wpps_track_user_email_confirmation( $user_id, $user_reg_successful ) {
    write_log("ur_track_user_email_confirmation triggered");

    // $user_reg_successful is either true or false. If it is false then the user's email is not verified yet.
    if( $user_reg_successful === true ) {
        //Use your code here to track event
        write_log("User reg successfull. User ID: " . $user_id);
        $user = wms_get_user_by( 'ID', $userID );
        write_log('Username: ' . $user->user_login);
        global $regpassword;
    }
}

// ACTION Failed Login
add_action( 'user_registration_login_failed' , 'wpps_user_registration_login_failed', 10);
function wpps_user_registration_login_failed() {
    write_log("Login fail");
}

// ACTION New User Approved
add_action( 'ur_user_approved', 'wpps_ur_user_approved', 10, 1);
function wpps_ur_user_approved( $userID) {
    write_log("New User approved. User ID: " . $userid);    
}

// ACTION: User Status updated:
add_action( 'ur_user_status_updated', 'wpps_ur_user_status_updated', 10, 3);
function wpps_ur_user_status_updated($status,$userID,$alertUser) {
    write_log("User status updated. User ID: " . $userid);  
}

// ACTION User Resets Password
add_action( 'user_registration_reset_password', 'wpps_user_registration_reset_password', 10, 1);
function wpps_user_registration_reset_password($user_id) {
    write_log("User reset password. User ID: " . $user_id); 
}

function wms_get_user_by( $field, $value ) {
    $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value ); 
    if ( ! $userdata ) {
        return false;
    } 
    $user = new WP_User;
    $user->init( $userdata ); 
    return $user;
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to demonstrate how the other plugin is actually firing `ur_user_approved` and the other hooks?

Comment: Thanks Kero, but I don't understand your request. Do you mean include some example functions from the User Registrations plugin that fire these hooks?

Comment: You wrote "I opened up the User Registration plugin in Visual Studio code and did a search in 'includes' on "do_action" This returned a number of possible functions that deal with that" - can you share these findings? I don't have or know the plugin you're trying too hook into with your `add_action()` calls.